# Powershell extract local html tag

Tags: powershell

I am novice powershell user please bear with that. I have tried to parse html table in powershell for strings between tags, 
Here is the HTML

```
    <head>
        <title>HTML TABLE</title>
        </head><body>
        <table>
        <colgroup><col/><col/></colgroup>
        <tr><th>TestcaseName</th><th>Status</th></tr>
        <tr><td>abcd </td><td>First </td></tr>
        <tr><td>xyz </td><td>Second </td></tr>
        <tr><td>pqr </td><td>Third </td></tr>
        </table>
        </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code which I have tried

```
$arr = @()
$path = "C:\test.html"
$pattern =  '(?i)<tr[^>]*><td[^>]*>(.*)</td><td>'

Get-Content $path | Foreach {if ([Regex]::IsMatch($_, $pattern)) {
           $arr += [Regex]::Match($_, $pattern)
            }
        }
$arr | Foreach {$_.Value}
```

Expected output is

```
abcd
xyz
pqr
```

But it results in

```
<tr><td>abcd </td><td>
<tr><td>xyz </td><td> 
<tr><td>pqr </td><td>
```

Can anyone mention why the tags are also getting as output and how to avoid this. Also I want to append text to each array elements eg: `<a href="\\192.116.1.2\cluster_110">abcd, <a href="\\192.116.1.3\cluster_110">xyz` etc, please mention the same as it involves special characters.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is always going to be valid xml, you could cast it to xml and do something like the below:

```
[xml] $xml = Get-Content $path

$xml.SelectNodes("//tr") |
  Where-Object {$_.ChildNodes.Count -gt 0 -and $_.ChildNodes[0].Name -eq 'td'} |
  ForEach-Object {$_.ChildNodes[0].InnerText}
```

You can append whatever you like to the results inside the ForEach-Object

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?<=\<td\>)(.*?(?=\</td\>))
```

The reason the tags are picked up is the same reason the inside of the tags are picked up. Unless you specify, Regex will return EVERYTHING it matches. You can use lookaround assertions to match text but exclude it from the capture, hence the ?<= and ?= in the regex above.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

As for appending, you can do this:

```
$Arr | Foreach {$Nope+ $_ + $ChuckTesta}
$Begin + $Arr[0] + $End
```

Doing this will implicitly convert it from a Match to a String; you have been warned. I don't think there is a way to do this while keeping it a Match but I'm probably wrong in assuming.